# How to accept yaml file types in html input

Tags: javascript, file-upload, yaml

How can I accept YAML file types (both `YAML` and `yml` extensions) in an HTML input? I tried `<input accept="$1" />` where `$1` is `text/x-yaml`, `text/x-yaml`, `application/x-yaml` and `text/vnd.yaml` but none of them works. It always shows All files (*) in the file picker UI. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try `accept=".yml,.yaml"`.